# How many tasks to put in Calendar per day?

Tags: time-management

I'm a PhD student trying to get organised. My timetable is flexible so I can manage how many tasks I can do everyday but I'm asking how many is reliable thing to do? is it 2? 3? I hate it when I see the calendar is full! It makes me feeling overwhelmed.

Comment: Well, it depends a lot if the tasks take 5 minutes or 8 hours.

Comment: I recommend buying Getting Things Done by David Allen and following his process.  There is guidance on task sizes and tasks vs projects.  Even if this exact process doesn't work for you, you will be ready to adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, the length of tasks has a lot to do with it.

I  suggest you use a task manager instead of a calendar. Then there is less pressure if you dont do a task as it stays in the list.  You can set them up with different priority and completion dates. If you dont finish one that day, it will still remain in the list  and you can reschedule it.

I use Asana. Its available on different plarforms and syncs between them. It is free for single person use.

Answer (score 0):

> How many tasks to put in Calendar per day?

You put however many tasks need to be done that particular day.

> I hate it when I see the calendar is full! It makes me feeling overwhelmed.

You'll learn to get used to it.

Comment: Or you learn that tasks on a calendar are not a great way to run a research project...