# How to make a to do list (app) less overwhelming when looking at tasks?

Tags: task-management

I want to manage my tasks and assign specific days to complete them by. I have tried digital calendar and also tried a to do app. Th nice thing about the calendar is that it has weekly/monthly view. However, after working with it, it seemed for me it is more tailored to meetings/appointments.

On the other hand, the to-do app has one problem. It does not show at a glance weekly view or monthly view. So, when I look at the tasks, which has due date to be completed on, they seem to be a lot. I also have to figure our by looking closely to specific task if it is in this month or the next month. That was a little bit overwhelming for me.

How can I manage the tasks in less overwhelming way (taking into account that I like to add tasks for at least the next 6 months).

Comment: This comes close to asking for product recommendations, which is offtopic on most of Stack Exchange...

Comment: I am sure that you have asked this on another site. And the answer is the same. Plus, please do not cross post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many tasks to put in Calendar per day?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/193755/how-many-tasks-to-put-in-calendar-per-day)

Comment: Note this was previously asked by OP here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/195467/struggling-between-todo-list-and-calendar

Comment: I use Peril Sensitive Sunglasses (tm)

Comment: Your question may fit this site better: "**Software Recommendations - StackExchange**". Here is the link: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SolarMike, The OP has asked 3 questions on this site, and all 3 questions got downvotes. We all know that the reason for the downvotes is that all 3 questions are consistently **off-topic** for this site.  I am pretty sure that his  future questions may have the same fate. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you've tried a todo app and it didn't work for you, try another. They vary wildly because people's approaches to todos vary wildly. Some insist on time estimates or categories or priorities for every task. Some make it easy to filter by due date. Some hide things you've finished, others let you see what you have already got done. Spend a few hours playing with different apps and you might find one that works for you.

That said, for over a decade now I've used a plain text file with dates hand-typed and things to do each of those dates (not things due on those dates, but you could make your own choices) hand typed under them. Makes it easy to include urls or other details, have a single todo span multiple lines, and whatever other things I like that the app designer didn't think of.

I also know people who love paper systems, including binders with one sheet of paper per day. It's hard to copy an unfinished (or even unstarted) item to the next day, and they see that as a feature that encourages them to be realistic about when they are really going to do a particular thing.

Take the time to find a system that works for you. It's worth it.

Comment: A plain text file could be nice. But how do you make that portable? (e.g. on your mobile). And what you do if you didn't complete a task on its date?

Comment: Paper is still the killer app after 5000 years. Walking up to the airport gate in a foreign country and having the mobile boarding pass vanish is uniquely stressful. Paper doesn't do that. But then trying to get the boarding pass printed in a foreign country is difficult.

Comment: @Sahran I don't usually work with only a mobile. Sometimes I copy and paste a few lines (errands, say) from the text file into some communication app (skype, whatsapp etc etc) and send them to myself so I have them while I'm out. And if I don't complete a task as planned I copy and paste it to a date I think I will (eg don't roll Friday tasks to Saturday if they are really Monday.)

Comment: @Sahran Plain text is _the_ most portable format there is — there are countless programs that can handle it!  (I run an SSH server on my phone, so I can use rsync, scp, and many other programs to sync, transfer, merge, back up, track changes, etc. — but I know that won't apply to most folks.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like Asana. It's what I use.

Note that a calendar is for appointments, not for tasks. And a task manager is not for appointments. If you use the right tool for the job, it will work for you.

Comment: What should you use for tasks that have a date deadline, a calendar or a task manager?

Comment: Task manager which has deadline features.

Comment: Ideally one that permits breaking large tasks into subtasks.

Comment: Microsoft Project :-) Get Visio while you're at it haw, haw

Answer (score 0):

So for what it's worth, I use the free ToDoList by AbstractSpoon. I have also iterated a number of ways trying to use it to its best potential.

- It has a drop-down "Due Date" which can be filtered by Today, by End of This Week, End of Next Week, This Month, Next Month, etc.
- It has user-defined categories that can be used as view filters later.
- On a daily basis I usually "flag" around 10 items at most and filter to view, think, and work on just those items for the day.

This has been broadly helpful. Answers to the OP's prior question helped me personally to differentiate between calendar items (things I must interface with another person at a particular time) vs. todo-list items (things I can work on and get done at a time of my choosing, possibly with a defined due date).